# problem with voiceStateUpdate in JavaScript discord.js 12.2.0

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

When converting to the 12 version of discord.js there was a problem that creating private channels stopped working

Code:

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
    // ПРИВАТ КАНАЛЫ
    let server = bot.guilds.cache.get('724268046998437918');
    let member_oldchannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.get(oldMember.voice.channelID)
    let member_newchannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.get(newMember.voice.channelID);
    if (oldMember.voice.channelID == newMember.voice.channelID) return
    let member = server.members.cache.get(oldMember.id);
    if (member_newchannel) {
        if (member_newchannel.name == '・Создать приват') {
            let cat = server.channels.cache.get('724268048860577816');
            if (!cat) {
                console.log('Не могу найти категорию для создания канала.');
                member.send('`[AUTO] Ваша комната не была создана. Ошибка: не найдена категория. Передайте это сообщение тех. администраторам нашего Discord Сервера.`')
                return
            }
            if (member.voice.channel.id != '724268049137401911') {
                console.log('Юзер вышел из канала, комната не была создана');
                member.send('`[AUTO] Вы вышли из канала для создания комнаты. Комната не была создана.`');
                return
            }
            let rol = server.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == 'Jr. Discord Master')
            server.channel.create(` | ${member.user.username}`, { type: 'voice', permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: member.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'USE_VAD'],
                deny: ['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'MANAGE_ROLES_OR_PERMISSIONS', 'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS']
            }, {
                id: rol.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'USE_VAD', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS',],
                deny: ['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'MANAGE_ROLES_OR_PERMISSIONS', 'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS']
            },
            {
                id: serverid,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'CONNECT', 'SPEAK'],
                deny: ['MUTE_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'USE_VAD', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS']

            }
            ]}).then(private => {
                private.setParent(cat.id).catch(() => { private.setParent(cat.id); });
                private.setUserLimit('2')
                member.setVoiceChannel(private.id).catch(() => { private.delete(); });
            })
        }
    }

    if (member_oldchannel) {
        if (member_oldchannel.name.startsWith(" |")) {
            if (member_oldchannel.members.size != 0) return
            return member_oldchannel.delete();
        }
    }
});
```

There is absolutely no response from the bot in the console, the channel is not created, and there are no errors either.
**Even this simple code doesn't work**

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    let MainChannel = '724268049137401911';
    if (newState.voiceChannelID === MainChannel){
        console.log('1');
    }
});
```

Comment: In discord.js v12 discord provides 2 states in the voiceStateUpdate event, instead in your code you seem to use newMember and oldMember which is not correct. It will be easier if you look at this documentation: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate

Comment: ```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    let MainChannel = '724268049137401911';
    if (newState.voiceChannelID == MainChannel){
        console.log('1');
    }
});
```
You won't believe it but even this code doesn't work

Comment: If you are using discord.js v12 there isn't any property of newState called voiceChannelID, look at the docs